# d3js time scale same value but different results

Tags: d3.js, scale

I have two overlapping charts. One is a barchart and one is a linechart.
Both have in each data a date (the same date - same count of results) But if I calculate the attr x for each chart I get different results.

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
```

width = 860.
So I debugged very deep in d3js-code and recognized the following:

If I call x (x(d.value) and step into it I came to the following code:

```
    function d3_uninterpolateNumber(a, b) {
b = b - (a = +a) ? 1 / (b - a) : 0;
return function(x) {
  return (x - a) * b;
};
  }
```

I saw that **x** and **a** have the same value (x is a date (Tue Jul 2 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2013) and a are ticks (1372716000000 --> the ticks of the first date in my data) in case of 2nd of July.

But b has different values. So I have no idea what b is.
In case of barchart it is 3.7947783849423196e-10 and in case of LineChart it's 3.7947783849423196e-10
So the result of x(d.value) is different, but it shouldn't be.

Has anybody an idea?
I try to get a fiddle tomorrow, but maybe somebody has the answer without js-fiddle.

thx in advance
©a-x-i

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting different values when you pass the same value to the same scale?

Comment: Yes, so it is. I hope I find time to deliver the js-fiddle for this sample.

Comment: I would suspect that the values you pass in are different data types, e.g. one is a number and the other a string.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

To render the barchart and linechart I have two different functions. In each function I have called the x.domain.

In LineChart only:

```
x.domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.xValue; }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.xValue; })]);
```

But in BarChart:

```
var xMax = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.xValue; });
        xMax = new Date(xMax.toString()); // otherwise data[<last>].xValue is changed as well!
        if (ChartHandler.SelectedAggregationPeriod == ChartHandler.AggregationPeriod.month) {
            xMax.setTime(xMax.getTime() + 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //+12h
        }
 var xMin = d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.xValue; });

        x.domain([xMin, xMax]);
```

that's it....
©a-x-i

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  But you might want to look at [`d3.extent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) to compute max and min in one function call, and also the time scale's [`.nice()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-nice) function or [`time.ceil()` and `time.floor()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#wiki-interval_ceil) functions for extending your domain.